# Entity Relationship Diagramming: Understanding cardinality

Tags: database, erd, entity-relationship

I am having some trouble getting my head around cardinality in ER diagramming. I am linking an example I found to help me explain where I am getting confused.
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/download/dvd-rental-er-diagram/#

Question 1: 
The cardinality between Customer and Rental is 0:1. So that means a customer can take out zero or one rentals. I would have thought the customer would be able to take out 1 or many rentals (1:*) because a customer means that they are taking out a rental (can't be a customer if you are not spending any money) and that a customer could take out many rentals.

Question 2: 
Also for the Staff to Payment relationship. Staff to Payment is 0:1 cardinality. I would have thought that a staff would make at least one payment because payments are necessary for the rental transaction. And then in reverse (one payment can be made by one and only payment): just to clarify this is because logically a payment is a transaction that only be made by one person at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. The same thing occurs on both sides of `film_category`, which I believe represents a many-to-many relationship based on the primary key. I think the diagram was drawn incorrectly.

Note that there's no such thing as 0:1 cardinality, but rather 0/1:1. Also, despite what the site and diagram says, the diagram is a table diagram and not an ER diagram. The notation used doesn't support or distinguish all the concepts from the Entity-Relationship model. Proper ER diagrams use Chen's notation or something equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the answer. Good to know I wasn't completely misunderstanding it. I was using UML notation for cardinality as that is what is recommended in my textbook and 0:1 was how they described it but it is a couple of years old so is possibly out of date. Thanks again.